# inserting keyword to hive based on keyword matched by flume

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive, flume

Im following one of the many twitter analysis tutorials using Hadoop, one of the things that I need to be able to do is have a column with the matched keyword in, for example, flume is configured to stream data from Twitter for the keywords "expo, uk, and liverpool" for example, then I need to be able to have a record stating which keyword the tweet was matched on

Comment: Hi Kevin, Could you solve this problem? If so, please update the solution.

Comment: im still working on it unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you have provided, I can say that [Flume Interceptor](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-interceptors) can solve your use-case.

Comment: thats what I was thinking,using the regex interceptor but when i use that I dont get any header added, even if I use the timestamp or host example that doesnt do anything

Comment: You have to post your flume config for anyone to help you.